# Entropy when having symbols with same probability

Tags: digital-communications, information-theory

I am trying to work out this problem:

Assume that we are transmitting data from a dictionary of 15 symbols. Let the 
probability of sending one symbol be the same as that of sending any other 
symbol. Calculate how often we need to fetch a symbol to transmit information at 
a rate of 5 bits/s.

How can this be found?

Comment: It would be nice if you write also what you may have thought or tried to do.

Comment: I am starting to learn about entropy, all I basically know is the formula of entropy which in this case I think is not applicable since the probabilities are not given

Comment: @user1930901: 15 equally likely symbols means each symbol has a probability of $1/15$. See my answer for a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** Compute the entropy $H$ of your source and note that in your case it represents the  number of bits required to represent each symbol. Then from

$\quad H$ [bits/symbol] $\times$ $x$ [symbols/second] = $5$ [bits/second]

compute $x$.

Comment: how can you compute the entropy if the probabilities are not given?

Comment: @user1930901: They are given. All symbols are equally likely.